# WordPress custom meta boxes not saving for pages

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason when I save a page, the meta box information isn't saving. It works perfectly fine for posts though. I originally had it working on my localhost, but after putting it online it seems to have somehow broken it.

```
function framework_add_meta_box() {
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

    foreach( $screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'framework_pagebgimage',
            __( 'Background Options', 'framework' ),
            'framework_bg_image',
            $screen,
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'framework_add_meta_box' );

function framework_bg_image( $post ) {
    global $post;

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'framework_meta_box', 'framework_meta_box_nonce' );

    $style = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bgimage_style', true );

    if( !$style ) {
        $style = 'background';
    }

    /* Featured Image Style */
    echo '<label for="bgimage_style">';
    _e( 'Featured Image Style:', 'framework' );
    echo '</label><br />';
    echo '<select id="bgimage_style" name="bgimage_style">';
    echo '<option value="background" ' . selected( $style, 'background', false ) . '>Background Image</option>';
    echo '<option value="standard" ' . selected( $style, 'standard', false ) . '>Standard</option>';
    echo '</select><br /><br />';
}

function framework_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['framework_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['framework_meta_box_nonce'], 'framework_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['bgimage_style'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $style = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['bgimage_style'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bgimage_style', $style );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'framework_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Comment: try removing `global $post;` inside the first function

Comment: that's how I actually had it at first and it still wasn't working

Comment: your code works, I've just tested it. however you should remove that `global $post;`, it's replacing the `$post` argument passed to the function with the homonym global variable. if it doesn't work online something else is the cause. try disabling the plugins and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I removed the global $post but still not working. Also deactivated all plugins and that didn't do it. You said that code is working for you, are you testing with pages?

Comment: Just tested on my PC again and actually seems to be broken there too.

Comment: yes, I've tested posts and pages

Comment: I had some other functions to add meta boxes to posts that were actually conflicting with the functions I pasted above. Found the problem now. Thanks for your help, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: no problem, glad you found the cause

Answer (score 1):

Verify the `$_POST['post_type']` value.

Also, instead of use the `$_POST` value I would use the second parameter in the function, something like this:

```
function framework_save_meta_box_data( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['framework_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['framework_meta_box_nonce'], 'framework_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['bgimage_style'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $style = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['bgimage_style'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bgimage_style', $style );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'framework_save_meta_box_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I added $post to the function: function framework_save_meta_box_data( $post_id, $post ) { and got this error: Warning: Missing argument 2 for framework_save_meta_box_data(). Also changed 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] to $post->post_type and set global $post and it didn't throw an error.. but still didn't fix anything. Also, what do you mean verify $_POST['post_type'] value?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the args number in the add_action line add_action( 'save_post', 'framework_save_meta_box_data', 10, 2 ); please try again.